# How to create a pointer to a byte array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, byte

i would like to create a pointer to a new byte array and i want to initialize it at once.

For example this could be used for an empty byte array:

```
byte *test = new byte[10];
```

but how can i create the pointer to the byte array and initialize it at once?

```
byte *test = new byte {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
```

...doesnt work though.

So how is it done anyway?

Comment: I have no knowledge whatsoever about C++ (hence this being a comment), but in several other languages, it would be something like `new byte[] {...}` (note the `[]`)

Comment: consider using `byte test[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03};`, then using `&test` if you need its address. There's no need to manually manage memory if the array is static.

Comment: @RedAlert there is almost never need to manually manage memory in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating arrays dynamically, consider creating vectors instead:

```
std::vector<byte> test{0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
```

(Requires C++11.) You can get at a pointer to the bytes by using `&test[0]`.

Comment: A program compiled on windows 10 that uses vector gives unreliable results when executed on XP. Why is that? Is `std::vector` not implemented on XP?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<byte> test{ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
```

Now you have `test.data()` as your pointer. Oh, and now you have automatic memory management as well. And `size()`. And `begin()` and `end()`. Oh and also exception safety.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using the C++17 `std::byte` type (the `-std=c++17` compiler flag should be used):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...Args>
std::vector<std::byte> init_byte_vector(Args&& ...args){
    return std::vector<std::byte>{static_cast<std::byte>(args)...};
}

int main(void)
{
    auto v = init_byte_vector(0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03);
    auto v_ptr = v.data();
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If your array is on the stack, you could do:

```
// Assume byte is typedef'd to an actual type
byte test[10]={0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}; // The remainder of the bytes will be
                                        // initialized with 0x00

// Now use test directly, or you can create a pointer to point to the data
byte *p=test;
```

For heap allocations, prefer `std::vector` with [uniform initialization](http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init) as others have already stated.